# the state is not updating after setting new

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and facing a problem. I am fetching data from an API using Axios then I have to set that data into state and pass that value in another component as props.
My problem is i am changing state using `this.setState` after fetching API , but the state is not changing. So I am sharing my code below.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
       employeeData:[]    // setting empty value
    }

}

ComponentDidMount(){
  console.log("Current State"+JSON.stringify(this.state)) ///output = []

  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/get/all")  
                                          /// getting values , can see them in network                 
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ employeeData: data }) ///setting new value
    console.log(this.state.employeeData)   /// can see fetched data 
   })
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
  console.log("2Nd STATE "+this.state)  /// again empty state, there is no fetched data
}
```

Then I have to pass that state in another component.

```
render(){
return(
<div className=" col-md-12" style={viewData}>

       <div >
            <p><b>All Employee Details</b></p>         
       </div>

       <Table data={this.state.employeeData}/>
</div>

        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is async function which takes some time to set your new state values. So printing new state after this line will give you previous state only and not new state.

You need a [callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296), to check the changed state,

```
this.setState({ employeeData: data }, () => console.log("2Nd STATE "+this.state))
```

Another thing is, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is meant to reduce number of `.then()`. With axios you will get direct `JSON` value. You can remove 1 `.then()`.

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/get/all") /// getting values , can see them in network                 
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ employeeData: response.data }, () => console.log("2Nd STATE "+this.state)) // This will give you new state value. Also make sure your data is in `response.data` it might be just `response`.
    console.log(this.state.employeeData)   // This will give you previous state only
   })
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log("2Nd STATE "+this.state)` is returning empty because it probably runs before that axios request completes.

Initially your render method gets called with empty state which is probably throwing an error. You need to handle the render with loading state until your request completes.

For example your render could look like this,

```
render() {
    return (!this.state.employeeData.length) ?
        (<div>Loading..</div>) :
        (
            <div className=" col-md-12" style={viewData}>

                <div >
                    <p><b>All Employee Details</b></p>
                </div>

                <Table data={this.state.employeeData} />
            </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: He is setting state once he is getting response from, So, It only renders once he sets to state. I hope you know it. Even though your solution is a good one, for a better UX, but it's not related to his query(I guess it's wrong with the way he used Axios).

Comment: Thanks @Gaurab Kc , your answer is helpful .

Comment: I think the problem is with the setState() , where  i had to use a callback function @dinesh

Comment: @ShakirUzZaman I didn't get what you mean by using a callback to setState. The issue I see with your code is that you used an unnecessary then which is not required and you can setState once you get the required response from your api which is done in the Resolve state(then) and you don't need a separate callback to setState.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async so you cannot see the change instantly where `setState()` is called. in order to view the change, you need to do a callback.

```
this.setState({ employeeData: data },()=>console.log(this.state.employeeData)) ///setting new value
```

change the code to above format and you can see the change in state once it is changed

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is where you are going wrong give it a try with this. It has got nothing to do with react. The way you used Axios is wrong.

```
ComponentDidMount(){
  console.log("Current State" + JSON.stringify(this.state));
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/get/all")
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ employeeData: response.data });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, both of these problems are occurring because Axios and this.setState() are asynchronous. Its hard to explain asynchronous programming in a single StackOverflow answer, so I would recommend checking this link: [https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-callbacks/][1]

But for now to get your code to work, switch it to this

```
ComponentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state); // Obviously empty state at beginning

  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/get/all")
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({employeeData: data}, () => { // Notice the additional function
      console.log(this.state); // You'll see your changes to state
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  console.log(this.state); // This won't work because Axios is asynchronous, so the state won't change until the callback from axios is fired
}
```

The part that most new React developers don't tend to realise is that this.setState() like axios is asynchronous, meaning the state doesn't change immediately, the task of actually doing that gets passed on as a background process. If you want to work with your state after it has changed, the this.setState() function provides a second parameter for doing just that

```
setState(stateChange[, callback])
```

taken from the react docs. Here the second parameter is a callback (a.k.a function) you can pass that will only get triggered after the state change occurs

```
// Assuming state = {name: "nothing"}
this.setState({name: "something"}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.name); // logs "something"
});
console.log(this.state.name); //logs "nothing"
```

Hope this helps!!.